# JavaScript multiple inheritance and instanceof

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, multiple-inheritance, ecmascript-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373644/javascript-multiple-inheritance)

Is there a way in JavaScript to do this:

```
Foo = function() {

};

Bar = function() {

};

Baz = function() {
    Foo.call(this);
    Bar.call(this);
};

Baz.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype, Bar.prototype);

var b = new Baz();
console.log(b);
console.log(b instanceof Foo);
console.log(b instanceof Bar);
console.log(b instanceof Baz);
```

So that Baz is both an instance of Foo and Bar?

Comment: This was discussed on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373644/javascript-multiple-inheritance

Comment: @IsmaelGhalimi so it was. I did read that question, and only its accepted answer. While there is an answer in there, I would not call this a duplicate.

Comment: Let me read it again and the answers to your question. I might have missed something. Sorry if I did.

Comment: The supplementary answer to another question is correct for this question. That how ever does not mean this question is a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript does not have multiple inheritance. `instanceof` tests the chain of prototypes, which is linear. You can have mixins, though, which is basically what you're doing with `Foo.call(this); Bar.call(this)`. But it is not inheritance; in `Object.create`, the second parameter only gives properties to copy, and is not a parent.

Comment: If `instanceof` won't work, is there another way to test whether an object inherits from two different classes?

Comment: @streetlight: No. In JavaScript I think testing for capabilities makes more sense than testing for parentage. That is, say you inherit from `Dog`; instead of `if (x instanceof Dog) x.bark()`, you'd write `if (x.bark) x.bark();` (or safer but more verbose, `if (typeof(x.bark) == "function") x.bark()`).