# Why does Angular not declare all functions of objects on the prototype?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

Referring to this question: [Understanding better Javascript OOP architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314264/understanding-better-javascript-oop-architecture?noredirect=1#comment25134005_17314264)

Angular sets a closure variable called `self` to `this`. Later it's used in `handleLocationChange` to find the right `this`. I've looked at the [code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dialog/dialog.js) but can't find any example where `handleLocationChange` is called or registered.

In my answer to the above mentioned question I speculate that it's declared in the constructor's body because the event/publish/subscribe implementation will be passed `handleLocationChange` without the instance it's on so when it's called it can't use `.call` or `.apply` because the specific instance isn't known.

Maybe someone with Angular experience could explain how `handleLocationChange` is used, where is the function registered and why isn't it on the Dialog's prototype?

```javascript
function Dialog(opts) {

            var self = this, options = this.options = angular.extend({}, defaults, globalOptions, opts);
            this._open = false;

            this.backdropEl = createElement(options.backdropClass);
            if(options.backdropFade){
                // ...
            }

            this.handleLocationChange = function() {
                self.close();
            };

            // more functions
        }
```

I speculated handleLocation (and other functions) are declared within the constructor's body instead of the prototype because of the following situation:

```javascript
var eventSystem={
  events:{},
  add:function(eventname,fnCallback){
     if(!this.events[eventname]){
      this.events[eventname]=[];
     }
     this.events[eventname].push(fnCallback);
  },
  trigger:function(eventname){
    if(!this.events[eventname]){
      return;
    }
    var i=0;
    for(i=0;i<this.events[eventname].length;i++){
      this.events[eventname][i]();
    }
  }
};

var person=function(name){
  this.name=name;
};
person.prototype.sayName=function(){
  console.log("this is now:",this.toString());
    // logs this is now: function (){ console.log("this is now:...
    // so this is now the sayName function not the person instance
  console.log(this.name);//undefined: sayName doesn't have a name property
}
var jon=new person("jon");
eventSystem.add("sayname",jon.sayName);//add event and listener function
eventSystem.trigger("sayname");//trigger the event
```

Here is how it's solved setting a closure reference

```javascript
var eventSystem={
  events:{},
  add:function(eventname,fnCallback){
     if(!this.events[eventname]){
      this.events[eventname]=[];
     }
     this.events[eventname].push(fnCallback);
  },
  trigger:function(eventname){
    if(!this.events[eventname]){
      return;
    }
    var i=0;
    for(i=0;i<this.events[eventname].length;i++){
      this.events[eventname][i]();
    }
  }
};

var person=function(name){
  var self=this;// set closure ref to this
  this.name=name;
  this.sayName=function(){
    console.log(self.name);//use closure ref to get this
       // logs jon
  }
};
var jon=new person("jon");
eventSystem.add("sayname",jon.sayName);//add event and listener function
eventSystem.trigger("sayname");//trigger the event
```

Comment: Angular-Ui (the dialog directive) is not an official part of angularjs, I think you should make it clearer that you actually discuss a third party component

Comment: @Narretz Thank you, I am not sure what I'm discussing as I'm not using Angular. But am curious though why someone would define member functions inside the constructor like this. Have looked at the code on github but could not find where and how handleLocationChange is used. I already know you can simulate private variables like this at the expense of the user's cpu and memory but that does not seem to be the case here.