# Multiple inheritance/prototypes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype, multiple-inheritance

I've come to a point where I need to have some sort of rudimentary multiple inheritance happening in JavaScript. (I'm not here to discuss whether this is a good idea or not, so please kindly keep those comments to yourself.)

I just want to know if anyone's attempted this with any (or not) success, and how they went about it.

To boil it down, what I really need is to be able to have an object capable of inheriting a property from more than one prototype *chain* (i.e. each prototype could have its own proper chain), but in a given order of precedence (it will search the chains in order for the first definition).

To demonstrate how this is theoretically possible, it could be achieved by attaching the secondary chain onto the end of the primary chain, but this would affect all instances of any of those previous prototypes and that's not what I want.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think [dojo declare](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/declare.html#multiple-inheritance) handles multiple inheritance [src](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/_base/declare.js) also I have a feeling mootools does also, much of this is beyond me but I'm gonna have a quick read of [this](http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.3/mro/) as dojo suggests

Comment: Give a look to TraitsJS ([link 1](http://soft.vub.ac.be/~tvcutsem/traitsjs/index.html), [link 2](http://code.google.com/p/es-lab/wiki/Traits)) it's a really good alternative to multiple inheritance and mixins...

Comment: @Pointy because that's not very dynamic. I'd like to be able to pick up changes made to either parent chain as they occur. However that said, I may have to resort to this if it's just not possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [does javascript support multiple inheritance like C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887828/does-javascript-support-multiple-inheritance-like-c)

Comment: An interesting read about this: http://webreflection.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/wait-moment-javascript-does-support.html

Comment: "I'm not here to discuss whether this is a good idea or not, so please keep those comments to yourself." +1

Comment: @TI afaik dojo support multiple inheritance using C3 superclass linearization algo. But internally only the first class passed for multiple inheritance is a true superclass (based on protoype). The rest are mixins, and are mixed into the child class to produce the inheritance chain.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Multiple inheritance can be achieved in ECMAScript 6 by using [Proxy objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

#### Implementation

```js
function getDesc (obj, prop) {
  var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop);
  return desc || (obj=Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) ? getDesc(obj, prop) : void 0);
}
function multiInherit (...protos) {
  return Object.create(new Proxy(Object.create(null), {
    has: (target, prop) => protos.some(obj => prop in obj),
    get (target, prop, receiver) {
      var obj = protos.find(obj => prop in obj);
      return obj ? Reflect.get(obj, prop, receiver) : void 0;
    },
    set (target, prop, value, receiver) {
      var obj = protos.find(obj => prop in obj);
      return Reflect.set(obj || Object.create(null), prop, value, receiver);
    },
    *enumerate (target) { yield* this.ownKeys(target); },
    ownKeys(target) {
      var hash = Object.create(null);
      for(var obj of protos) for(var p in obj) if(!hash[p]) hash[p] = true;
      return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(hash);
    },
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, prop) {
      var obj = protos.find(obj => prop in obj);
      var desc = obj ? getDesc(obj, prop) : void 0;
      if(desc) desc.configurable = true;
      return desc;
    },
    preventExtensions: (target) => false,
    defineProperty: (target, prop, desc) => false,
  }));
}
```

#### Explanation

A proxy object consists of a target object and some traps, which define custom behavior for fundamental operations.

When creating an object which inherits from another one, we use `Object.create(obj)`. But in this case we want multiple inheritance, so instead of `obj` I use a proxy that will redirect fundamental operations to the appropriate object.

I use these traps:

- The [`has` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/has) is a trap for the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). I use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if at least one prototype contains the property.
- The [`get` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get) is a trap for getting property values. I use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the first prototype which contains that property, and I return the value, or call the getter on the appropriate receiver. This is handled by [`Reflect.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get). If no prototype contains the property, I return `undefined`.
- The [`set` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set) is a trap for setting property values. I use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the first prototype which contains that property, and I call its setter on the appropriate receiver. If there is no setter or no prototype contains the property, the value is defined on the appropriate receiver. This is handled by [`Reflect.set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/set).
- The [`enumerate` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/enumerate) is a trap for [`for...in` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). I iterate the enumerable properties from the first prototype, then from the second, and so on. Once a property has been iterated, I store it in a hash table to avoid iterating it again.
  **Warning**: This trap has been removed in ES7 draft and is deprecated in browsers.
- The [`ownKeys` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/ownKeys) is a trap for [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames). Since ES7, `for...in` loops keep calling [[GetPrototypeOf]] and getting the own properties of each one. So in order to make it iterate the properties of all prototypes, I use this trap to make all enumerable inherited properties appear like own properties.
- The [`getOwnPropertyDescriptor` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) is a trap for [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor). Making all enumerable properties appear like own properties in the `ownKeys` trap is not enough, `for...in` loops will get the descriptor to check if they are enumerable. So I use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the first prototype which contains that property, and I iterate its prototypical chain until I find the property owner, and I return its descriptor. If no prototype contains the property, I return `undefined`. The descriptor is modified to make it configurable, otherwise we could break some proxy invariants.
- The [`preventExtensions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/preventExtensions) and [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/defineProperty) traps are only included to prevent these operations from modifying the proxy target. Otherwise we could end up breaking some proxy invariants.

There are more traps available, which I don't use

- The [`getPrototypeOf` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/getPrototypeOf) could be added, but there is no proper way to return the multiple prototypes. This implies `instanceof` won't work neither. Therefore, I let it get the prototype of the target, which initially is null.
- The [`setPrototypeOf` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/setPrototypeOf) could be added and accept an array of objects, which would replace the prototypes. This is left as an exercice for the reader. Here I just let it modify the prototype of the target, which is not much useful because no trap uses the target.
- The [`deleteProperty` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/deleteProperty) is a trap for deleting own properties. The proxy represents the inheritance, so this wouldn't make much sense. I let it attempt the deletion on the target, which should have no property anyway.
- The [`isExtensible` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/isExtensible) is a trap for getting the extensibility. Not much useful, given that an invariant forces it to return the same extensibility as the target. So I just let it redirect the operation to the target, which will be extensible.
- The [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/apply) and [`construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/construct) traps are traps for calling or instantiating. They are only useful when the target is a function or a constructor.

#### Example

```js
// Creating objects
var o1, o2, o3,
    obj = multiInherit(o1={a:1}, o2={b:2}, o3={a:3, b:3});

// Checking property existences
'a' in obj; // true   (inherited from o1)
'b' in obj; // true   (inherited from o2)
'c' in obj; // false  (not found)

// Setting properties
obj.c = 3;

// Reading properties
obj.a; // 1           (inherited from o1)
obj.b; // 2           (inherited from o2)
obj.c; // 3           (own property)
obj.d; // undefined   (not found)

// The inheritance is "live"
obj.a; // 1           (inherited from o1)
delete o1.a;
obj.a; // 3           (inherited from o3)

// Property enumeration
for(var p in obj) p; // "c", "b", "a"
```

Comment: Aren't there some performance issues that would become relevant even on normal scale applications?

Comment: @TomášZato It will be slower than data properties in a normal object, but I don't think it will be much worse than accessor properties.

Comment: TIL: `multiInherit(o1={a:1}, o2={b:2}, o3={a:3, b:3})`

Comment: I would consider replacing "Multiple inheritance" by "Multiple delegation" to get a better idea of whats going on. The key concept in your implementation its that the proxy is actually choosing the right object to _delegate_  (or forward) the message. The power of your solution is that you can extend the target prototype/s dynamically.
Other answers are using concatenation (ala `Object.assign`) or getting a quite different graph, in the end all of them are getting one-an-only prototype chain between objects.
The proxy solution offers a runtime branching, and this rocks!

Comment: About performance, if you create an object which inherits from multiple objects, which inherit from multiple objects, and so on, then it will become exponential. So yes, it will be slower. But in normal cases I don't think it will be that bad.

Answer (score 18):

**Update (2019):** The original post is getting pretty outdated. [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190111044453/http://justinfagnani.com/2015/12/21/real-mixins-with-javascript-classes/) (now internet archive link, since domain went away) and its associated [GitHub library](https://github.com/justinfagnani/mixwith.js) are a good modern approach.

**Original post:**
Multiple inheritance [edit, not proper inheritance of type, but of properties; mixins] in Javascript is pretty straightforward if you use constructed prototypes rather than generic-object ones. Here are two parent classes to inherit from:

```
function FoodPrototype() {
    this.eat = function () {
        console.log("Eating", this.name);
    };
}
function Food(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Food.prototype = new FoodPrototype();


function PlantPrototype() {
    this.grow = function () {
        console.log("Growing", this.name);
    };
}
function Plant(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Plant.prototype = new PlantPrototype();
```

Note that I have used the same "name" member in each case, which could be a problem if the parents did not agree about how "name" should be handled. But they're compatible (redundant, really) in this case.

Now we just need a class that inherits from both. Inheritance is done by **call**ing the constructor function (without using the new keyword) for the prototypes and the object constructors. First, the prototype has to inherit from the parent prototypes

```
function FoodPlantPrototype() {
    FoodPrototype.call(this);
    PlantPrototype.call(this);
    // plus a function of its own
    this.harvest = function () {
        console.log("harvest at", this.maturity);
    };
}
```

And the constructor has to inherit from the parent constructors:

```
function FoodPlant(name, maturity) {
    Food.call(this, name);
    Plant.call(this, name);
    // plus a property of its own
    this.maturity = maturity;
}

FoodPlant.prototype = new FoodPlantPrototype();
```

Now you can grow, eat, and harvest different instances:

```
var fp1 = new FoodPlant('Radish', 28);
var fp2 = new FoodPlant('Corn', 90);

fp1.grow();
fp2.grow();
fp1.harvest();
fp1.eat();
fp2.harvest();
fp2.eat();
```

Comment: Can you do this with built in prototypes? (Array, String, Number)

Comment: I don't think the built-in prototypes have constructors you can call.

Comment: Well, I can do `Array.call(...)` but it doesn't seem to affect whatever I pass as `this`.

Comment: @TomášZato You could do `Array.prototype.constructor.call()`

Comment: @RoyJ The link to the article is dead, do you have any other?

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Thanks for letting me know. I've replaced the link with a link to the archived web page.

Comment: Isn't this kind of like using `Object.assign(target, source)`? If you "inherited" from anything this way you would get all the properties, but they would essentially be copied into the new prototype. Any changes made to the original prototypes would not be reflected in the new object, so it's not real inheritance, just copying properties from multiple objects. I use Object.assign for this all the time. It works, but technically, it's copying, not true inheritance where all children point back to the same parent object. They're pointing to their own properties.

Comment: Yes, which is why I have "not proper inheritance of type, but of properties; mixins" in the text.

Comment: This doesn't work with function in prototype. How can I inherit multiple prototypies?

Comment: @JohnWinston It's hard to know what you're trying to do. You should probably ask a new question.

Answer (score 7):

This one uses `Object.create` to make a real prototype chain:

```
function makeChain(chains) {
  var c = Object.prototype;

  while(chains.length) {
    c = Object.create(c);
    $.extend(c, chains.pop()); // some function that does mixin
  }

  return c;
}
```

For example:

```
var obj = makeChain([{a:1}, {a: 2, b: 3}, {c: 4}]);
```

will return:

```
a: 1
  a: 2
  b: 3
    c: 4
      <Object.prototype stuff>
```

so that `obj.a === 1`, `obj.b === 3`, etc.

Comment: Just a quick hypothetical question: I wanted to make Vector class by mixing Number and Array prototypes (for fun). This would give me both array indexes and math operators. But would it work?

Comment: @TomášZato, it's worth checking [this article](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/) out if you're looking into subclassing arrays; it could save you some headache. good luck!

Answer (score 5):

I like John Resig's implementation of a class structure: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

This can be simply extended to something like:

```
Class.extend = function(prop /*, prop, prop, prop */) {
    for( var i=1, l=arguments.length; i<l; i++ ){
        prop = $.extend( prop, arguments[i] );
    }

    // same code
}
```

which will allow you to pass in multiple objects of which to inherit.  You're going to lose `instanceOf` capability here, but that's a given if you want multiple inheritance.

---

my rather convoluted example of the above is available at https://github.com/cwolves/Fetch/blob/master/support/plugins/klass/klass.js

Note that there is some dead code in that file, but it allows multiple inheritance if you want to take a look.

---

If you want chained inheritance (NOT multiple inheritance, but for most people it's the same thing), it can be accomplished with Class like:

```
var newClass = Class.extend( cls1 ).extend( cls2 ).extend( cls3 )
```

which will preserve the original prototype chain, but you'll also have a lot of pointless code running.

Comment: That creates a merged shallow clone. Adding a new property to the "inherited" objects will not cause the new property to appear on the derived object, as it would in true prototype inheritance.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker -- True, but if you want "multiple inheritance" in that one class derives from two classes, there isn't really an alternative.  Modified answer to reflect that simply chaining classes together is the same thing in most cases.

Comment: It seems your GitHUb is gone do you still have https://github.com/cwolves/Fetch/blob/master/support/plugins/klass/klass.js I wouldn't mind looking at it if you care to share?

Answer (score 5):

I offer a function to allow classes to be defined with multiple inheritance. It allows for code like the following:

```
let human = new Running({ name: 'human', numLegs: 2 });
human.run();

let airplane = new Flying({ name: 'airplane', numWings: 2 });
airplane.fly();

let dragon = new RunningFlying({ name: 'dragon', numLegs: 4, numWings: 6 });
dragon.takeFlight();
```

to produce output like this:

```
human runs with 2 legs.
airplane flies away with 2 wings!
dragon runs with 4 legs.
dragon flies away with 6 wings!
```

Here are what the class definitions look like:

```
let Named = makeClass('Named', {}, () => ({
  init: function({ name }) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}));

let Running = makeClass('Running', { Named }, protos => ({
  init: function({ name, numLegs }) {
    protos.Named.init.call(this, { name });
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
  },
  run: function() {
    console.log(`${this.name} runs with ${this.numLegs} legs.`);
  }
}));

let Flying = makeClass('Flying', { Named }, protos => ({
  init: function({ name, numWings }) {
    protos.Named.init.call(this, { name });
    this.numWings = numWings;
  },
  fly: function( ){
    console.log(`${this.name} flies away with ${this.numWings} wings!`);
  }
}));

let RunningFlying = makeClass('RunningFlying', { Running, Flying }, protos => ({
  init: function({ name, numLegs, numWings }) {
    protos.Running.init.call(this, { name, numLegs });
    protos.Flying.init.call(this, { name, numWings });
  },
  takeFlight: function() {
    this.run();
    this.fly();
  }
}));
```

We can see that each class definition using the `makeClass` function accepts an `Object` of parent-class names mapped to parent-classes. It also accepts a function that returns an `Object` containing properties for the class being defined. This function has a parameter `protos`, which contains enough information to access any property defined by any of the parent-classes.

The final piece required is the `makeClass` function itself, which does quite a bit of work. Here it is, along with the rest of the code. I've commented `makeClass` quite heavily:

```js
let makeClass = (name, parents={}, propertiesFn=()=>({})) => {
  
  // The constructor just curries to a Function named "init"
  let Class = function(...args) { this.init(...args); };
  
  // This allows instances to be named properly in the terminal
  Object.defineProperty(Class, 'name', { value: name });
  
  // Tracking parents of `Class` allows for inheritance queries later
  Class.parents = parents;
  
  // Initialize prototype
  Class.prototype = Object.create(null);
  
  // Collect all parent-class prototypes. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`
  // will get us the best results. Finally, we'll be able to reference
  // a property like "usefulMethod" of Class "ParentClass3" with:
  // `parProtos.ParentClass3.usefulMethod`
  let parProtos = {};
  for (let parName in parents) {
    let proto = parents[parName].prototype;
    parProtos[parName] = {};
    for (let k of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)) {
      parProtos[parName][k] = proto[k];
    }
  }
  
  // Resolve `properties` as the result of calling `propertiesFn`. Pass
  // `parProtos`, so a child-class can access parent-class methods, and
  // pass `Class` so methods of the child-class have a reference to it
  let properties = propertiesFn(parProtos, Class);
  properties.constructor = Class; // Ensure "constructor" prop exists
  
  // If two parent-classes define a property under the same name, we
  // have a "collision". In cases of collisions, the child-class *must*
  // define a method (and within that method it can decide how to call
  // the parent-class methods of the same name). For every named
  // property of every parent-class, we'll track a `Set` containing all
  // the methods that fall under that name. Any `Set` of size greater
  // than one indicates a collision.
  let propsByName = {}; // Will map property names to `Set`s
  for (let parName in parProtos) {
    
    for (let propName in parProtos[parName]) {
      
      // Now track the property `parProtos[parName][propName]` under the
      // label of `propName`
      if (!propsByName.hasOwnProperty(propName))
        propsByName[propName] = new Set();
      propsByName[propName].add(parProtos[parName][propName]);
      
    }
    
  }
  
  // For all methods defined by the child-class, create or replace the
  // entry in `propsByName` with a Set containing a single item; the
  // child-class' property at that property name (this also guarantees
  // there is no collision at this property name). Note property names
  // prefixed with "$" will be considered class properties (and the "$"
  // will be removed).
  for (let propName in properties) {
    if (propName[0] === '$') {
      
      // The "$" indicates a class property; attach to `Class`:
      Class[propName.slice(1)] = properties[propName];
      
    } else {
      
      // No "$" indicates an instance property; attach to `propsByName`:
      propsByName[propName] = new Set([ properties[propName] ]);
      
    }
  }
  
  // Ensure that "init" is defined by a parent-class or by the child:
  if (!propsByName.hasOwnProperty('init'))
    throw Error(`Class "${name}" is missing an "init" method`);
  
  // For each property name in `propsByName`, ensure that there is no
  // collision at that property name, and if there isn't, attach it to
  // the prototype! `Object.defineProperty` can ensure that prototype
  // properties won't appear during iteration with `in` keyword:
  for (let propName in propsByName) {
    let propsAtName = propsByName[propName];
    if (propsAtName.size > 1)
      throw new Error(`Class "${name}" has conflict at "${propName}"`);
    
    Object.defineProperty(Class.prototype, propName, {
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
      value: propsAtName.values().next().value // Get 1st item in Set
    });
  }
  
  return Class;
};

let Named = makeClass('Named', {}, () => ({
  init: function({ name }) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}));

let Running = makeClass('Running', { Named }, protos => ({
  init: function({ name, numLegs }) {
    protos.Named.init.call(this, { name });
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
  },
  run: function() {
    console.log(`${this.name} runs with ${this.numLegs} legs.`);
  }
}));

let Flying = makeClass('Flying', { Named }, protos => ({
  init: function({ name, numWings }) {
    protos.Named.init.call(this, { name });
    this.numWings = numWings;
  },
  fly: function( ){
    console.log(`${this.name} flies away with ${this.numWings} wings!`);
  }
}));

let RunningFlying = makeClass('RunningFlying', { Running, Flying }, protos => ({
  init: function({ name, numLegs, numWings }) {
    protos.Running.init.call(this, { name, numLegs });
    protos.Flying.init.call(this, { name, numWings });
  },
  takeFlight: function() {
    this.run();
    this.fly();
  }
}));

let human = new Running({ name: 'human', numLegs: 2 });
human.run();

let airplane = new Flying({ name: 'airplane', numWings: 2 });
airplane.fly();

let dragon = new RunningFlying({ name: 'dragon', numLegs: 4, numWings: 6 });
dragon.takeFlight();
```

The `makeClass` function also supports class properties; these are defined by prefixing property names with the `$` symbol (note that the final property name that results will have the `$` removed). With this in mind, we could write a specialized `Dragon` class that models the "type" of the Dragon, where the list of available Dragon types is stored on the Class itself, as opposed to on the instances:

```
let Dragon = makeClass('Dragon', { RunningFlying }, protos => ({
  
  $types: {
    wyvern: 'wyvern',
    drake: 'drake',
    hydra: 'hydra'
  },
  
  init: function({ name, numLegs, numWings, type }) {
    protos.RunningFlying.init.call(this, { name, numLegs, numWings });
    this.type = type;
  },
  description: function() {
    return `A ${this.type}-type dragon with ${this.numLegs} legs and ${this.numWings} wings`;
  }
}));

let dragon1 = new Dragon({ name: 'dragon1', numLegs: 2, numWings: 4, type: Dragon.types.drake });
let dragon2 = new Dragon({ name: 'dragon2', numLegs: 4, numWings: 2, type: Dragon.types.hydra });
```

## The Challenges of Multiple Inheritance

Anyone who followed the code for `makeClass` closely will note a rather significant undesirable phenomenon occurring silently when the above code runs: **instantiating a `RunningFlying` will result in TWO calls to the `Named` constructor!**

This is because the inheritance graph looks like this:

```
 (^^ More Specialized ^^)

      RunningFlying
         /     \
        /       \
    Running   Flying
         \     /
          \   /
          Named

  (vv More Abstract vv)
```

When there are *multiple paths to the same parent-class in a sub-class' inheritance graph*, instantiations of the sub-class will invoke that parent-class' constructor multiple times.

Combatting this is non-trivial. Let's look at some examples with simplified classnames. We'll consider class `A`, the most abstract parent-class, classes `B` and `C`, which both inherit from `A`, and class `BC` which inherits from `B` and `C` (and hence conceptually "double-inherits" from `A`):

```
let A = makeClass('A', {}, () => ({
  init: function() {
    console.log('Construct A');
  }
}));
let B = makeClass('B', { A }, protos => ({
  init: function() {
    protos.A.init.call(this);
    console.log('Construct B');
  }
}));
let C = makeClass('C', { A }, protos => ({
  init: function() {
    protos.A.init.call(this);
    console.log('Construct C');
  }
}));
let BC = makeClass('BC', { B, C }, protos => ({
  init: function() {
    // Overall "Construct A" is logged twice:
    protos.B.init.call(this); // -> console.log('Construct A'); console.log('Construct B');
    protos.C.init.call(this); // -> console.log('Construct A'); console.log('Construct C');
    console.log('Construct BC');
  }
}));
```

If we want to prevent `BC` from double-invoking `A.prototype.init` we may need to abandon the style of directly calling inherited constructors. We will need some level of indirection to check whether duplicate calls are occurring, and short-circuit before they happen.

We could consider changing the parameters supplied to the properties function: alongside `protos`, an `Object` containing raw data describing inherited properties, we could also include a utility function for calling an instance method in such a way that parent methods are also called, but duplicate calls are detected and prevented. Let's take a look at where we establish the parameters for the `propertiesFn` `Function`:

```
let makeClass = (name, parents, propertiesFn) => {
  
  /* ... a bunch of makeClass logic ... */
  
  // Allows referencing inherited functions; e.g. `parProtos.ParentClass3.usefulMethod`
  let parProtos = {};
  /* ... collect all parent methods in `parProtos` ... */

  // Utility functions for calling inherited methods:
  let util = {};
  util.invokeNoDuplicates = (instance, fnName, args, dups=new Set()) => {
    
    // Invoke every parent method of name `fnName` first...
    for (let parName of parProtos) {
      if (parProtos[parName].hasOwnProperty(fnName)) {
        // Our parent named `parName` defines the function named `fnName`
        let fn = parProtos[parName][fnName];
        
        // Check if this function has already been encountered.
        // This solves our duplicate-invocation problem!!
        if (dups.has(fn)) continue;
        dups.add(fn);
        
        // This is the first time this Function has been encountered.
        // Call it on `instance`, with the desired args. Make sure we
        // include `dups`, so that if the parent method invokes further
        // inherited methods we don't lose track of what functions have
        // have already been called.
        fn.call(instance, ...args, dups);
      }
    }
    
  };
  
  // Now we can call `propertiesFn` with an additional `util` param:
  // Resolve `properties` as the result of calling `propertiesFn`:
  let properties = propertiesFn(parProtos, util, Class);
  
  /* ... a bunch more makeClass logic ... */
  
};
```

The whole purpose of the above change to `makeClass` is so that we have an additional argument supplied to our `propertiesFn` when we invoke `makeClass`. We should also be aware that every function defined in any class may now receive a parameter after all its others, named `dup`, which is a `Set` that holds all functions that have already been called as a result of calling the inherited method:

```
let A = makeClass('A', {}, () => ({
  init: function() {
    console.log('Construct A');
  }
}));
let B = makeClass('B', { A }, (protos, util) => ({
  init: function(dups) {
    util.invokeNoDuplicates(this, 'init', [ /* no args */ ], dups);
    console.log('Construct B');
  }
}));
let C = makeClass('C', { A }, (protos, util) => ({
  init: function(dups) {
    util.invokeNoDuplicates(this, 'init', [ /* no args */ ], dups);
    console.log('Construct C');
  }
}));
let BC = makeClass('BC', { B, C }, (protos, util) => ({
  init: function(dups) {
    util.invokeNoDuplicates(this, 'init', [ /* no args */ ], dups);
    console.log('Construct BC');
  }
}));
```

This new style actually succeeds in ensuring `"Construct A"` is only logged once when an instance of `BC` is initialized. But there are three downsides, the third of which is *very critical*:

1. This code has become less readable and maintainable. A lot of complexity hides behind the `util.invokeNoDuplicates` function, and thinking about how this style avoids multi-invocation is non-intuitive and headache inducing. We also have that pesky `dups` parameter, which really needs to be defined on *every single function in the class*. Ouch.
2. This code is slower - quite a bit more indirection and computation is required to achieve desirable results with multiple inheritance. Unfortunately this is likely to be the case with *any* solution to our multiple-invocation problem.
3. **Most significantly, the structure of functions which rely on inheritance has become *very rigid***. If a sub-class `NiftyClass` overrides a function `niftyFunction`, and uses `util.invokeNoDuplicates(this, 'niftyFunction', ...)` to run it without duplicate-invocation, `NiftyClass.prototype.niftyFunction` will call the function named `niftyFunction` of every parent class that defines it, ignore any return values from those classes, and finally perform the specialized logic of `NiftyClass.prototype.niftyFunction`. This is the *only possible structure*. If `NiftyClass` inherits `CoolClass` and `GoodClass`, and both these parent-classes provide `niftyFunction` definitions of their own, `NiftyClass.prototype.niftyFunction` will never (without risking multiple-invocation) be able to:

- **A.** Run the specialized logic of `NiftyClass` first, *then* the specialized logic of parent-classes
- **B.** Run the specialized logic of `NiftyClass` at any point other than *after* all specialized parent logic has completed
- **C.** Behave conditionally depending on the return values of its parent's specialized logic
- **D.** Avoid running a particular parent's specialized `niftyFunction` altogether

Of course, we could solve each lettered problem above by defining specialized functions under `util`:

- **A.** define `util.invokeNoDuplicatesSubClassLogicFirst(instance, fnName, ...)`
- **B.** define `util.invokeNoDuplicatesSubClassAfterParent(parentName, instance, fnName, ...)` (Where `parentName` is the name of the parent whose specialized logic will be immediately followed by the child-classes' specialized logic)
- **C.**  define `util.invokeNoDuplicatesCanShortCircuitOnParent(parentName, testFn, instance, fnName, ...)` (In this case `testFn` would receive the result of the specialized logic for the parent named `parentName`, and would return a `true/false` value indicating whether the short-circuit should happen)
- **D.** define `util.invokeNoDuplicatesBlackListedParents(blackList, instance, fnName, ...)` (In this case `blackList` would be an `Array` of parent names whose specialized logic should be skipped altogether)

These solutions are all available, *but this is total mayhem*! For every unique structure that an inherited function call can take, we would need a specialized method defined under `util`. What an absolute disaster.

With this in mind we can start to see the challenges of implementing good multiple inheritance. The full implementation of `makeClass` I provided in this answer does not even consider the multiple-invocation problem, or many other problems which arise regarding multiple inheritance.

This answer is getting very long. I hope the `makeClass` implementation I included is still useful, even if it isn't perfect. I also hope anyone interested in this topic has gained more context to keep in mind as they do further reading!

Answer (score 4):

Don't get confused with JavaScript framework implementations of multiple inheritance.

All you need to do is use [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to create a new object each time with the specified prototype object and properties, then be sure to change the [Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) each step of the way if you plan on instantiating `B` in the future.

To inherit instance properties `thisA` and `thisB` we use [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) at the end of each object function. This is optional if you only care about inheriting the prototype.

Run the following code somewhere and observe `objC`:

```
function A() {
  this.thisA = 4; // objC will contain this property
}

A.prototype.a = 2; // objC will contain this property

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;

function B() {
  this.thisB = 55; // objC will contain this property

  A.call(this);
}

B.prototype.b = 3; // objC will contain this property

C.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);
C.prototype.constructor = C;

function C() {
  this.thisC = 123; // objC will contain this property

  B.call(this);
}

C.prototype.c = 2; // objC will contain this property

var objC = new C();
```

- `B` inherits the prototype from `A`
- `C` inherits the prototype from `B`
- `objC` is an instance of `C`

This is a good explanation of the steps above:

[OOP In JavaScript: What You NEED to Know](http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/)

Comment: Doesn't this copy all the properties into the new object, though? So if you have two prototypes, A and B, and you recreate them both on C, changing a property of A will not affect that property on C and visa versa. You will end up with a copy of all the properties in A and B stored in memory. It would be the same performance as if you had hard coded all the properties of A and B into C. It's nice for readability, and property lookup doesn't have to travel to parent objects, but it's not really inheritance - more like cloning. Changing a property on A doesn't change the cloned property on C.

Comment: This isn't what the OP asked. This is just single inheritance. If you `var objB = new B()` you'll find `objB instanceof A` is true. If the types the OP wanted to mix-in to type `Tank` were `Weapon` and `Vehicle`, in your solution a `Weapon` would have to be a `Vehicle` or vice versa. Neither of which make sense.

Answer (score 2):

I’m in no way an expert on javascript OOP, but if I understand you correctly you want something like (pseudo-code):

```
Earth.shape = 'round';
Animal.shape = 'random';

Cat inherit from (Earth, Animal);

Cat.shape = 'random' or 'round' depending on inheritance order;
```

In that case, I’d try something like:

```
var Earth = function(){};
Earth.prototype.shape = 'round';

var Animal = function(){};
Animal.prototype.shape = 'random';
Animal.prototype.head = true;

var Cat = function(){};

MultiInherit(Cat, Earth, Animal);

console.log(new Cat().shape); // yields "round", since I reversed the inheritance order
console.log(new Cat().head); // true

function MultiInherit() {
    var c = [].shift.call(arguments),
        len = arguments.length
    while(len--) {
        $.extend(c.prototype, new arguments[len]());
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just picking the first prototype and ignoring the rest? Setting `c.prototype` multiple times doesn't yield multiple prototypes. For example, if you had `Animal.isAlive = true`, `Cat.isAlive` would still be undefined.

Comment: Yea, I was meaning to mix the prototypes, corrected... (I used jQuery’s extend here, but you get the picture)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to implement multiple inheritance in JavaScript, although very few libraries does it.

I could point [Ring.js](http://ringjs.neoname.eu), the only example I know.

Answer (score 2):

I was working on this a lot today and trying to achieve this myself in ES6. The way I did it was using Browserify, Babel and then I tested it with Wallaby and it seemed to work. My goal is to extend the current Array, include ES6, ES7 and add some additional custom features I need in the prototype for dealing with audio data.

Wallaby passes 4 of my tests. The example.js file can be pasted in the console and you can see that the 'includes' property is in the prototype of the class. I still want to test this more tomorrow.

**Here's my method: (I will most likely refactor and repackage as a module after some sleep!)**

```
var includes = require('./polyfills/includes');
var keys =  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(includes.prototype);
keys.shift();

class ArrayIncludesPollyfills extends Array {}

function inherit (...keys) {
  keys.map(function(key){
      ArrayIncludesPollyfills.prototype[key]= includes.prototype[key];
  });
}

inherit(keys);

module.exports = ArrayIncludesPollyfills
```

Github Repo:
https://github.com/danieldram/array-includes-polyfill

Answer (score 2):

I think it is ridiculously simple. The issue here is that the child class will only refer to `instanceof` for the first class you call

https://jsfiddle.net/1033xzyt/19/

```
function Foo() {
  this.bar = 'bar';
  return this;
}
Foo.prototype.test = function(){return 1;}

function Bar() {
  this.bro = 'bro';
  return this;
}
Bar.prototype.test2 = function(){return 2;}

function Cool() {
  Foo.call(this);
  Bar.call(this);

  return this;
}

var combine = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
$.extend(combine, Object.create(Bar.prototype));

Cool.prototype = Object.create(combine);
Cool.prototype.constructor = Cool;

var cool = new Cool();

console.log(cool.test()); // 1
console.log(cool.test2()); //2
console.log(cool.bro) //bro
console.log(cool.bar) //bar
console.log(cool instanceof Foo); //true
console.log(cool instanceof Bar); //false
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below which IS showing support for multiple inheritance. Done by using **PROTOTYPAL INHERITANCE**

```
function A(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
A.prototype.setName = function (name) {

    this.name = name;
}

function B(age) {
    this.age = age;
}
B.prototype.setAge = function (age) {
    this.age = age;
}

function AB(name, age) {
    A.prototype.setName.call(this, name);
    B.prototype.setAge.call(this, age);
}

AB.prototype = Object.assign({}, Object.create(A.prototype), Object.create(B.prototype));

AB.prototype.toString = function () {
    return `Name: ${this.name} has age: ${this.age}`
}

const a = new A("shivang");
const b = new B(32);
console.log(a.name);
console.log(b.age);
const ab = new AB("indu", 27);
console.log(ab.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of the package [IeUnit](http://ieunit.sourceforge.net/TestFramework.html).

The concept assimilation implemented in IeUnit seems to offers what you are looking for in a quite dynamical way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of **prototype chaining using constructor functions**:

```
function Lifeform () {             // 1st Constructor function
    this.isLifeform = true;
}

function Animal () {               // 2nd Constructor function
    this.isAnimal = true;
}
Animal.prototype = new Lifeform(); // Animal is a lifeform

function Mammal () {               // 3rd Constructor function
    this.isMammal = true;
}
Mammal.prototype = new Animal();   // Mammal is an animal

function Cat (species) {           // 4th Constructor function
    this.isCat = true;
    this.species = species
}
Cat.prototype = new Mammal();     // Cat is a mammal
```

This concept uses Yehuda Katz's definition of a **"class"** for JavaScript:

> ...a JavaScript "class" is just a Function object that serves as a constructor plus an attached prototype object. ([Source: Guru Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/))

Unlike the [Object.create approach](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html), when the classes are built in this way and we want to create instances of a "class", we don't need to know what each "class" is inheriting from. We just use `new`.

```
// Make an instance object of the Cat "Class"
var tiger = new Cat("tiger");

console.log(tiger.isCat, tiger.isMammal, tiger.isAnimal, tiger.isLifeform);
// Outputs: true true true true
```

The order of precendence should make sense. First it looks in the instance object, then it's prototype, then the next prototype, etc.

```
// Let's say we have another instance, a special alien cat
var alienCat = new Cat("alien");
// We can define a property for the instance object and that will take 
// precendence over the value in the Mammal class (down the chain)
alienCat.isMammal = false;
// OR maybe all cats are mutated to be non-mammals
Cat.prototype.isMammal = false;
console.log(alienCat);
```

We can also modify the prototypes which will effect all objects built on the class.

```
// All cats are mutated to be non-mammals
Cat.prototype.isMammal = false;
console.log(tiger, alienCat);
```

I originally wrote some of this up with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25189960/1766230).

Comment: The OP is asking for multiple prototype chains (eg `child` inherits from `parent1` and `parent2`). Your example only talks about one chain.

Answer (score 0):

A latecomer in the scene is [SimpleDeclare](https://github.com/mercmobily/simpleDeclare). However, when dealing with multiple inheritance, you will still end up with copies of the original constructors. That's a necessity in Javascript...

Merc.

Comment: That's a necessity in Javascript... until ES6 Proxies.

Comment: Proxies are interesting! I will definitely look into changing SimpleDeclare so that it won't need to copy methods over using proxies once they become part of the standard. SimpleDeclare's code is really, really easy to read and change...

Answer (score 0):

I would use [ds.oop](https://github.com/digital-synapse/ds.oop). Its similar to prototype.js and others. makes multiple inheritance very easy and its minimalist. (only 2 or 3 kb) Also supports some other neat features like interfaces and dependency injection

```
/*** multiple inheritance example ***********************************/

var Runner = ds.class({
    run: function() { console.log('I am running...'); }
});

var Walker = ds.class({
    walk: function() { console.log('I am walking...'); }
});

var Person = ds.class({
    inherits: [Runner, Walker],
    eat: function() { console.log('I am eating...'); }
});

var person = new Person();

person.run();
person.walk();
person.eat();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this, it implements multiple inheritance in JavaScript:

```
    class Car {
        constructor(brand) {
            this.carname = brand;
        }
        show() {
            return 'I have a ' + this.carname;
        }
    }

    class Asset {
        constructor(price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
        show() {
            return 'its estimated price is ' + this.price;
        }
    }

    class Model_i1 {        // extends Car and Asset (just a comment for ourselves)
        //
        constructor(brand, price, usefulness) {
            specialize_with(this, new Car(brand));
            specialize_with(this, new Asset(price));
            this.usefulness = usefulness;
        }
        show() {
            return Car.prototype.show.call(this) + ", " + Asset.prototype.show.call(this) + ", Model_i1";
        }
    }

    mycar = new Model_i1("Ford Mustang", "$100K", 16);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = mycar.show();
```

And here's the code for specialize_with() utility function:

```
function specialize_with(o, S) { for (var prop in S) { o[prop] = S[prop]; } }
```

This is real code that runs. You can copy-paste it in html file, and try it yourself. It does work.

That's the effort to implement MI in JavaScript. Not much of code, more of a know-how.

Please feel free to look at my complete article on this, https://github.com/latitov/OOP_MI_Ct_oPlus_in_JS

Answer (score 0):

I just used to assign what classes I need in properties of others, and add a proxy to auto-point to them i like:

```
class A {
    constructor()
    {
        this.test = "a test";
    }

    method()
    {
        console.log("in the method");
    }
}

class B {
    constructor()
    {
        this.extends = [new A()];

        return new Proxy(this, {
            get: function(obj, prop) {

                if(prop in obj)
                    return obj[prop];

                let response = obj.extends.find(function (extended) {
                if(prop in extended)
                    return extended[prop];
            });

            return response ? response[prop] : Reflect.get(...arguments);
            },

        })
    }
}

let b = new B();
b.test ;// "a test";
b.method(); // in the method
```