# extending Backbone class from multiple classes using prototype chain

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I came across a non-standard or unusual way of extending Backbone object
 by setting up prototype chain.

Scenario:
 - Child class inherits from two super classes
 - Two super classes are not related
 - hence SuperB = SuperA.extend is not applicable

For example: 
From ChildC scope SuperA.prototype.initialize.apply works as expected.

Yet how to extend ChildC so SuperA class methodA is available in ChildC scope
using the prototype.initialize.apply analogy?

```
SuperA = Backbone.Model
  defaults:
    flagA: false
  initialize: ->
    this.set "flagA", true
    console.log "SuperA::initialize()"
  methodA: ->
    console.log "methodA"

SuperB = Backbone.Model.extend
  defaults:
    flagB: false
  initialize: ->
    this.set "flagB", true  
    console.log "SuperB::initialize()"
  methodB: ->
    console.log "methodB"


ChildC = Backbone.Model.extend
  defaults:
    flagC: false
  initialize: ->
    SuperA.prototype.initialize.apply this, arguments 
    SuperB.prototype.initialize.apply this, arguments
    this.set "flagC", true
    console.log "ChildC::initialize()"
  methodC: ->
    console.log "methodC"


instanceA = new SuperA()
instanceA.methodA()

instanceB = new SuperB()
instanceB.methodB()

instanceC = new ChildC()
instanceC.methodC()

console.log instanceC.get("flagA")
console.log instanceC.get("flagB")
console.log instanceC.get("flagC")

instanceC.methodC()
```

Link to [Gist](https://gist.github.com/zemgalis/6155835)
Link to [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/uruzib/5/watch)

Comment: Use the `mixin` pattern to make the prototypes of A and B available on C. There's no way to do this with a prototype *chain*, it's not a tree.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple inheritance/prototypes in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163341/multiple-inheritance-prototypes-in-javascript)