# Prototypal Inheritance and prototype attribute

Tags: javascript

How can an object inherit from multiple parents in javascript?

I am thinking one would do this:

```
Fruit.prototype = new Plant ();
Fruit.prototype = new anotherPlant ();
```

But what will the Fruit's prototype attribute (prototype object) get set to? Will it still be the original Parent.prototype of the original Parent constructor function of Fruit?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163341/multiple-inheritance-prototypes-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Infact, not many languages support multiple inheritance.

All you are doing there is setting the `prototype` of `Fruit` to an instance of `Plant`, and then *overwriting* it with an instance of `anotherPlant`. It's the same as simply;

```
Fruit.prototype = new anotherPlant ();
```

However, don't forget that JavaScript has an *inheritance chain*. Using the above, if `anotherPlant` had `Plant` as it's prototype, you'd inherit from both objects.

```
function Plant() {

}

Plant.prototype.foo = 'foo';
Plant.prototype.baz = 'baz-a';

function AnotherPlant() {

}

AnotherPlant.prototype = new Plant();

AnotherPlant.prototype.bar = 'bar';
AnotherPlant.prototype.baz = 'baz-b';

var a = new AnotherPlant();

console.log(a.foo); // foo
console.log(a.bar); // bar
console.log(a.baz); // baz-b
```

JavaScript does inheritance differently to most other languages; it uses prototypical inheritance, which means the language determines the inheritance chain of a function (a *class*, if that makes it easier) by following the `prototype` property of the constructor function used to create the instance.

Comment: hmmm.... Matt also if I do Fruit.prototype = new Plant (); I am setting the prototype attribute (not the prototype property) to point to Plant.prototype  So does a prototype has both characteristics ie its used to define prototypal properties for children to inherit and also a prototypal attribute to point to a parent. ie its the same thing doing two things?

Comment: @Tomatoes: If you do that, you'd inherit the `foo` and `baz` properties of `Plant`. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: srry i wasnt clear, I am trying to distinguish between the prototype property and the prototype attribute and trying to figure out what the Fruit.prototype = new Plant (); statement it affecting. Seems like this one statement may well be doing two things. Inheritance = inheriting Plant.prototype methods AND assigning Plant.prototype as its prototype object (parent pointer).

Comment: @Tomatoes: A property and an attribute are the same thing. `Fruit.prototype = new Plant()` is setting the prototype property (or attribute) of `Fruit` to a new instance of `Plant`. JavaScript's inheritance is prototypical, rather the class-based, which may be what is confusing you; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming

Comment: how can it be though? one is defining properties for its child instances to inherit and the other is a pointer to its own parent. srry I am coming from another language. yeah checked all the tuts and everything. still dont know how one thing can do two different things.

Comment: that wiki page doesnt answer my question but appreciate the help.

Comment: also, i understand prototypal inheritance and how it follows the chain I just cant distinguish between the behavior i mentioned above.

Comment: i got it now. Prototype attribute is just a characteristic which tells us who the parent is so we can go up the chain. Prototype property lets us set methods and properties which children can inherit. Prototype does both because prototype attribute is just a characteristic.