# how can i inherit from 2 objects and use both the objects as a prototype of another

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am learning js inheritance and prototyping and my naming is probably totally off i am sorry for that.

i am trying to create a super object and prototype 2 sub object as properties and then inside one of the sub object call a function that is found in the other. it doesn't work for some reason.

**UPDATE**

my goal in here is:
I am trying to make a small game - for fun and practice.
My plan was  to have 1 basic object called(object) that has positioning and other properties (that every other object will have) another object called(controls) for controls. Only objects that can move will have that object as well.

players are also objects and they will have both "object" and "controls". as their prototype.

Hope that cleared things a bit.

Code:

```
    // sub Object1
function object(){
    this.speed = 1;
    this.walkDistant = 5;

}

// sub Object2
function controls(){
    this.moveLeft = function(){
        console.log(this.speed , this.walkDistant);
        return this.speed * this.walkDistant;
    }
}

// super Object
function player(){
    // DoesNothing
}

player.prototype.object  = new object();
player.prototype.controls  = new controls();

var firstPlayer = new player();
console.log(firstPlayer.controls.moveLeft());
```

Or if you prefer fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rMaKa/1/

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense, I think you're mixing things...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple inheritance/prototypes in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163341/multiple-inheritance-prototypes-in-javascript)

Comment: I've update my post with a more detailed explanation probably should have included it from the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a Player **can be** controlled you can mix in Controls with Player. Your object constructor function is a badly chosen name because a constructor function should start with a capital making it Object and you'd overwrite window.Object (bad idea). For this reason I've renamed it to Base. Player **is a** Base object and **can be** controlled so **inherits** from Base and has Controls **mixed in**.

For more information about constructor functions, mix ins, instance members and prototype check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).

```
function Base() {
  this.speed = 1;
  this.walkDistant = 5;
}

// sub Object2
function Controls() {
}
Controls.prototype.moveLeft = function() {
  console.log(this.speed, this.walkDistant);
  return this.speed * this.walkDistant;
}

// super Object
function Player() {
  //make player have Base instance members
  Base.call(this);
  //make player heve Controls instance members
  Controls.call(this);
}
//player is a base object
Player.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
//repair constrictor
Player.prototype.constructor = Player;
//Player can be controlled, copy controls prototype on player (mixin)
// this would be better suited in a helper function, see link posted in answer
var stuff;
for (stuff in Controls.prototype) {
  if (Controls.prototype.hasOwnProperty(stuff)) {
    Player.prototype[stuff] = Controls.prototype[stuff];
  }
}

var firstPlayer = new Player();

console.log(firstPlayer.moveLeft());
```

If you want the player to **have** controls you can try something like this:

```
function Controls(what) {
  //what do we need to control
  this.controlWhat=what;
}
Controls.prototype.moveLeft = function() {
  console.log(this.controlWhat.speed, this.controlWhat.walkDistant);
  return this.controlWhat.speed * this.controlWhat.walkDistant;
};

function Player() {
  this.speed = 1;
  this.walkDistant = 5;
  this.controls=new Controls(this);
}
var firstPlayer = new Player();

console.log(firstPlayer.controls.moveLeft());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer very much, mind explaining why did you do `Player.prototype.constructor = Player;` ? and why not just using new instead of `Player.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
//repair constrictor` ?

Comment: The link I posted should answer both questions

Comment: yes it did, thanks very much seems things doesnt work exactly as i thought

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mixins](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/) to extend the functionality of an object using functionality already implemented in other objects. You could also have it that the sub-objects know about the super object as below.

```
function subClassA(containerClass) {
    this.containerClass = containerClass;
    this.methodA = function() {
        console.log(this.containerClass.b.methodB());
    }
}

function subClassB(containerClass) {
    this.containerClass = containerClass;
    this.methodB = function() {
        return 12345;
    }
}

function containerClass() {
    this.a = new subClassA(this);
    this.b = new subClassB(this);
}

var cc = new containerClass();
cc.a.methodA();
```

The Mixin approach would look something like this:

```
// extend function to add mixin support
function extend(destination, source) {
    for (var k in source) 
      if (source.hasOwnProperty(k))
        destination[k] = source[k];
    return destination;
}

function subClassA() { }
subClassA.prototype.methodA = function() {
    console.log(this.methodB());
};

function subClassB() { }
subClassB.prototype.methodB = function() {
    return 12345;
};

function superClass() {
    // ----------------
}

// add the subClassA and subClassB functionality
extend(superClass.prototype, subClassA.prototype);
extend(superClass.prototype, subClassB.prototype);

var sc = new superClass();
sc.methodA();
```

Comment: yea I've done something like that before i was sure that there's a way to do it with prototype  i mean both of the objects are under the same parent how comes they dont know of eachother ?

Comment: @NetaMeta The shouldn't know about each other. It just doesn't work like that.

Comment: @NetaMeta I have updated the answer to include a solution using Mixins. See if this is more suitable for you.

Comment: Your mixin example would not work if you update subClassa.prototype after you've used it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access a property that pertences to `subObj1` from `subObj2`, but is the `superObj` that inherit both.

To achieve that, you should make your `subObj1` inherit the `subObj2`.

```
// sub Object1
function name(){
    this.name = function(){
        var myName = 'FirstName';
        console.log(myName, this.last.lastName);
    }

    this.callName = function(){
        this.name();
    };
}

// sub Object2
function lastName(){
    this.lastName ='someLastName';
}

// super Object
function fullName(){
    // DoesNothing
}

name.prototype.last  = new lastName();
fullName.prototype.name  = new name();

var myName = new fullName();
myName.name.callName();
```

You can see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rMaKa/3/)

Comment: This would add the lastName() functionality to all name() objects. If I understood correct I don't think that is wanted.

Comment: i dont want sub object 1 and subobject 2 to be related, they are 2 separate objects, their only relation is through the super object.

Comment: @NetaMeta Child object can access properties from their parents, but not from another childs. You should move your `moveLeft` method to your super class to achieve what you want (but that does not make sense either). I think that we have a problem related to the OO concept instead of JS specific.

Comment: what you mean related to the oo concept. what approach should i take instead?

Comment: @NetaMeta You are on the right way, but I think that you should rethink your classes. `controls` is using information that exists on the `object` class, what seems, to me, that `controls` should inherit `object`. Or you can put this information on `player` or on `controls` itself.

Comment: The issue is player also need need object's properties not only conrtols also other class(physics) also need some of the properties, i am thinking maybe i should make my object as the super object while others extend it.