# understanding javascript inheritence

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am learning javascript inheritance so I am trying the following code:

```
var obj = function(name) {
  this.name=name
};

var obj1 = new obj("suman"); 
console.log(obj1.name); 

var obj2 = new obj1("sonali"); 
console.log(obj2.name);
```

But when I try getting `obj2.name` I get the following error `object is not a function`.

As per my understanding `var obj1` is inheriting properties from `obj` . So when I am inheriting `obj2` from `obj1` it should inherit  name property also. Please guide me where I am wrong.

Comment: Simplest way is to use `obj1` as the prototype for `obj2`: `var obj2=new Object(obj1);`.

Comment: because obj1 is not a new  object but an instance of obj. to see multiple inheritance sample go to :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163341/multiple-inheritance-prototypes-in-javascript, for article on java script inheritance see: http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html

Comment: where did you find this code ?

Comment: You can not inherit from an object. You can inherit from class. In your case class it's a function `obj`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but when I am trying for `obj2.name`, I am getting error object is not a function.

Not exactly. You're getting that error when you call `var obj2=new obj1("sonali");` - where `obj1` is the first instance, not your constructor. Use

```
var obj2 = new obj("sonali");
console.log(obj2.name); // works as expected
```

For better readability, the convention is to capitalise the names of constructor functions, so `function Obj(name){…}` and `var obj = new Obj(…)`.

> per my understanding `obj1` is inheriting properties from `obj`

No, `obj1` is an *instance*. It does have the `.name` property on itself, it doesn't inherit it, it does own it. `obj` is the constructor function that *created* the property as part of the instance initialisation.

`obj1` does inherit properties from `obj.prototype` - since you didn't create any custom ones, the only inherited property is `obj1.constructor`.

> So when I am inheriting `obj2` from `obj1` it should inherit name property also.

As stated above, that's not what's happening. `obj1` is not a constructor function, you cannot call it with `new`. I bet I'm confusing you now, but you can still inherit from the `obj1` instance object though: by using [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). Let's start with

```
function Obj(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
var obj1 = new Obj("suman"); // or alternatively:
obj1 = Object.create(Obj.prototype); obj1.name = "suman";

console.log(obj1.name); // suman
```

Now we can create a new object, inheriting [prototypically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) from the first object:

```
var obj2 = Object.create(obj1);
console.log(obj2.name); // suman - inherited!
console.log(obj2.hasOwnProperty("name")); // false - it's inherited!
```

But now we can give it an own name as well:

```
obj2.constructor("sonali"); // which executes the following:
obj2.name = "sonali"; // pretty equivalent

console.log(obj2.name); // sonali
```

Comment: Thanks @Bergi it really helped me to understand

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the concepts of 'class' and 'instance' which have specific meanings in Object Oriented literature.

In your example, obj refers to the class/protoype or broadly speaking, a "template" that is used as a reference for creating copies. 
The object reference provided in the statement using the new operator is the 'instance' created for the class. So, obj1 is a valid instance.

So, only classes can be instantiated and not their instances. 
To answer your question instantiating a class does not lead to the child 'inheriting' the ability to be instantiated further.

Hence, the objects you wish to create should always refer the 'class' you wish to use while calling the constructor with the new keyword.