# How to inherit 2 Class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have Class A and B. I want to inherit both class using Class C. For Class A, i am using below code -

It's working fine for single class. Now i want to inherit class B.

```
function A () {
}

function B () {
}

function C () {
}

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

Now How C inherit A?

```
//B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
//B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

Comment: hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163341/multiple-inheritance-prototypes-in-javascript

Comment: Note: In your example, you're missing the necessary call to `A` from `C`: `A.call(this);`

Answer (score 3):

An object only has a *single* prototype chain. Unless there's a relationship between `A.prototype` and `B.prototype`, they can't both be on a single object's prototype chain.

You can create a new object that contains a combination of what's on `A.prototype` and `B.prototype` and use that as the object for `C.prototype`:

```
function C() {
    A.call(this);
    B.call(this);
}
C.prototype = Object.assign({}, A.prototype, B.prototype); // Object.assign is
                                                           // ES2015, but can be
                                                           // shimmed
C.prototype.constructor = C;
```

...but note that:

1. If you add/remove things on `A.prototype` or `B.prototype` afterward, those changes won't be reflected by `C.prototype` or on instances created via `new C`.
2. `instanceof` will not consider an object created via `new C` as being `instanceof A` or `instanceof B` because `A.prototype` and `B.prototype` are not in its prototype chain.
3. If `A.prototype` and `B.prototype` both have the same property (perhaps they both override `toString`, for instance), you can only have one or the other. (In the code above, `B.prototype` would win.)

Comment: I am getting a problem on this code you can see on this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988171/multiple-inheritance-console-output

Comment: @pankaj98: Yes, but it's a different question. *This* question is answered, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple-Inheritance does not work in JS.

Instead of building convoluted inheritance chains, though, why not try something like Mix-Ins / Traits?

Instead of trying to figure out if `WalkingSpeakingPet` should inherit from `WalkingPet` or `SpeakingPet`, you can instead use Traits, and add them to a pet.

```
function Walker (target) {
  return {
    walk (x, y) { console.log("I'm walking!"); }
  };
}

function Flyer (target) {
  return {
    fly (x, y, z) { console.log("I'm flying!"); }
  };
}

function Swimmer (target) {
  return {
    swim (x, y, z) { console.log("I'm swimming!"); }
  };
}


function Pet (type, name) {
  return { type, name };
}

function Dog (name) {
  const dog = Pet("Dog", name);
  return Object.assign(dog, Walker(dog));
}

function Parakeet (name) {
  const parakeet = Pet("Bird", name);
  return Object.assign(parakeet, Flyer(parakeet));
}

function HarveyTheWonderHamster () {
  const harvey = Pet("Hamster", "Harvey");
  return Object.assign(harvey, Walker(harvey), Flyer(harvey), Swimmer(harvey));
}
```