# Multiple inheritance console output

Tags: javascript, html

I am using below code. I'm getting wrong output console with my code. Right now i am getting "this is aB" but i required constructor related output on my output console. Like "this is aA" for first, "this is aB" for second, "this is aC" for third console.

```
function A () {
  this.name = "A";
}

A.prototype.a = function () {
  console.log("this is a"+this.name);
}

function B () {
  this.name = "B";
}

B.prototype.b = function () {
  console.log("this is b"+this.name);
}

function C() {
   this.name = "C";

    A.call(this);
    B.call(this);
}

C.prototype = Object.assign({}, A.prototype, B.prototype);
C.prototype.constructor = C;

C.prototype.c = function () {
  console.log("this is c"+this.name);
}

var x = new C();

x.a(); //this is aB
x.b(); //this is bB
x.c(); //this is cB
```

Comment: Your quoted output is not the output of that code. You've shown `aB` three times. In fact, the output is `aB`, `bB`, and `cB` (if we ignore the `undefined`s that get logged because you're logging the result of calling the methods, but the methods don't return anything).

Comment: I've fixed the issues raised in my comment above, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

`this` in all three constructors refers to the same object: The one created by the `new` operator. That one object can only have **one** `name` property. So whichever constructor you call last will "win" and the name will be assigned by that. Thus, you're seeing B all the time because even with `new C`, first `C` writes C, then `A` writes A (overwriting C), and finally `B` writes B (overwriting A).

If you want the code related to each level in the hierarchy to have its own `name` property, you cannot literally do that, but you can get close by having each one use its own property (e.g., `nameA`, `nameB`, and `nameC`). You can do this in a way that doesn't require you to remember which level you're writing the code at by using brackets notation and a variable shared by all the code for each level.

I'm not *recommending* that. Whatever the actual problem you're trying to solve is, there's probably a better solution.

But here's how you'd do it:

```js
var A = (function() {
    var name = "nameA";    // <== We declare a variable and put this level's property name in it

    function A() {
        this[name] = "A";  // <== Note we're using brackets notation here
    }

    A.prototype.a = function() {
      console.log("this is a: " + this[name]); // <== Brackets again here
    };

    return A;
})();

var B = (function() {
    var name = "nameB";    // <== Same again for B

    function B () {
        A.call(this);
        this[name] = "B";
    }

    B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
    B.prototype.constructor = B;

    B.prototype.b = function() {
        console.log("this is b: " + this[name]);
    };

    return B;
})();

var C = (function() {
    var name = "nameC";

    function C() {
        B.call(this);
        this[name] = "C";
    }

    C.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);
    C.prototype.constructor = C;

    C.prototype.c = function() {
        console.log("this is c: " + this[name]);
    };

    return C;
})();

var x = new C();

x.a(); //this is aA
x.b(); //this is bB
x.c(); //this is cC
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

The one object all three constructors work with will end up with three properties: `nameA`, `nameB`, and `nameC`.

Again, I'm not recommending that, just pointing out that it's possible, and can suit some problems, although it's unclear whether it suits yours.

---

That was 2016. Here in 2020, you'd probably solve this with [private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). You can use them with a transpiler now and support is being actively added to JavaScript engines:

```js
// NOTE: Only works in environments that support private fields (such as
// modern Chromium-based browsers)
class A {
    #name; // <== Private field, only accessible to A's code

    constructor() {
        this.#name = "A";
    }

    a() {
        console.log("this is a: " + this.#name);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    #name; // <=== Private field, only accessible to B's code

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.#name = "B";
    }

    b() {
        console.log("this is b: " + this.#name);
    }

}

class C extends B {
    #name; // <=== Private field, only accessible to C's code

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.#name = "C";
    }

    c() {
        console.log("this is c: " + this.#name);
    }
}

const x = new C();

x.a(); // tthis is a: A
x.b(); // tthis is b: B
x.c(); // tthis is c: C
```

The one object created by `new C` will have a different private `#name` field for each class.

Comment: *(FWIW, if you're interested in how private fields work, I cover them in depth in my new book* JavaScript: The New Toys *which covers ES2015-ES2020. Details and links in my profile.)*