# javascript - Object.create more than one prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance, three.js, prototype, multiple-inheritance

I want my child object to inherit prototype of more than one parent, this doesnt work:

```
child.prototype = Object.create(parent1.prototype, parent2.prototype);
```

and also this:

```
child.prototype = Object.create(parent1.prototype);
child.prototype.add(Object.create(parent2.prototype));
```

any suggestions ?

EDIT : Im using THREE.JS with CHROME

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple inheritance/prototypes in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163341/multiple-inheritance-prototypes-in-javascript)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mef162yb/1/

Comment: What Arun P Johny has linked is multi-level inheritance. You can't do multiple inheritance the way you've described it in JavaScript like you can do in say C++. Can you give more information as to why you're wanting multiple inheritance and maybe we might be able to give an OM that will achieve the same result without requiring multiple inheritance.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Worth posting it in an answer I would say. Leaving a fiddle without any comment/explanation is not so useful for people ending up here.

Comment: This is not a three.js question.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have multiple inheritance, the only way to do it is just extending base class. Take a look at sample below, it's a bit adopted from [MDN Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

```
function SuperClass(){
  //class 1 - has some super staff
  console.log('SuperClass');
}
function OtherSuperClass(){
  //class 2 - has some other super staff
  console.log('OtherSuperClass');
}

//MyClass wants to inherit all supers staffs from both classes
function MyClass() {
  SuperClass.call(this);
  OtherSuperClass.call(this);
}

//inheritance and extension
//extend class using Object.assign
MyClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype); // inheritance
Object.assign(MyClass.prototype, OtherSuperClass.prototype); // extension

//define/override custom method
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {
  console.log('double inheritance method');
};
```

Comment: thats looking promising, but Im using THREE.JS with chrome so no `$` or `Object.assign` or `jQuery` for me...

Comment: Object.assign is like Object.create, it's browser thing

Comment: mybad, updated answer, it's typically `Object.assign({a:1}, {b:2})` returns `{a: 1, b: 2}`

Comment: Object.assign is a JavaScript thing, not a browser thing. As it is relatively new and not yet implemented in all browsers, you might want to use a polyfill: https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-assign

Comment: thanks for help @nils, i was just sayin' that browsers support it, no lib requried