# How to change Class's Prototype in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6

Following is my Class, Its prototype vale is not getting changed, (I am working on the Chrome console)

```js
class Rectangle {
    constructor(length, width) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    getArea() {
        return this.length * this.width;
    }

    static create(length, width) {
        return new Rectangle(length, width);
    }
}
```

and I am Changing the prototype of the Class to null

```js
Rectangle.prototype= null
```

When I try to access the changed Prototype, the value remains the same "Object" with 'getArea' prototype property of Rectangle

But in ES5 the prototype value is changed.

Comment: Edited the Question, did not mean the plain object as a result of null assingment

Comment: I misread your question, sorry. Deleted the comment.

Comment: A class's prototype is non-writable, if you really want to overwrite the prototype, use `function` instead, a function's prototype is writable, you can reassign it to any object you want.

Answer (score 4):

In ES6, the `.prototype` property of `class`es is not writable and not configurable<sup>1</sup>. Use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) where you do the assignment and you'll get  `ReferenceError` exception "*Invalid assignment in strict mode*".

<s>If you want to overwrite the `.prototype`</s> (which is a very bad idea in general), <s>you'll have to use `Object.defineProperty(Rectangle, "prototype", {value: …})`.</s>

<sub>1: See [§14.5.14 ClassDefinitionEvaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation), step 16: *Perform MakeConstructor(F, writablePrototype=false, prototype=proto).*</sub>

Comment: Hello! The `prototype` property of an ES6 class in non-configurable, so this answer won't work. Is there any other way? I'd like to wrap the class `prototype` with a Proxy.

Comment: @trusktr Thanks for the hint. I guess for that you would have to use an ES5 class definition, which you can still use in a `class extends` clause. Alternatively change your ES6 constructor to return an instance wrapped in a proxy (you can re-use the handler object). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31236132/1048572) for a similar undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 `prototype` property is handled in a special way as non-configurable. But one can use the [Object.setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) of `Object` to set a new value to the prototype of an object `X`, eg:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(X, proto)
```

```js
class Rectangle {
    constructor(length, width) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    getArea() {
        return this.length * this.width;
    }

    static create(length, width) {
        return new Rectangle(length, width);
    }
}

Rectangle.prototype = null;
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Rectangle));

Object.setPrototypeOf(Rectangle, null);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Rectangle));
```

You are warned that altering the prototype of objects has various side-effects, including **performance issues** and **possible inheritance issues**.

Unfortunately the following **won't work** because `prototype` is set as non-configurable initially.

```
Object.defineProperty(X, "prototype", {value: proto});
```