# can I add non static method to external class using prototypes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype

Can I add using prototypes function for a class instance?

so I'll be able to use `this` or `__proto__` keyword inside my method, for example:

```
class PersonClass {
  name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  sayHello() {
    console.log(`hello, my name is ${this.name} and I'm a ${this.type}`);
  }
}

PersonClass.prototype.type = "human";
PersonClass.prototype.PrintType = () => {
  console.log(`I'm a ${PersonClass.prototype.type}`);
};

const aria = new PersonClass("Ned Stark");
aria.sayHello();
aria.PrintType();
```

this code works of course, but I wish to add something like

```
PersonClass.prototype.SayHello2 = () => {
  console.log(this.name, caller.__proto__.name);
};
```

which of course fails.

is it even possible?

Comment: How exactly does it fail? Aren't classes compiled into "other primitives" (functions/objects) ? So if you can find that "other primitive" in the compiled code, surely you will be able to slap something onto the prototype. It's not "protected" afaik. Seems you can't with ES6: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680766/how-to-change-classs-prototype-in-es6 . How about extending the class like a normal person :p ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Class's Prototype in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680766/how-to-change-classs-prototype-in-es6)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "external class"?

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин no this is not solving my issue. actually someone just did answer the right answer, which is disappeared now

Comment: @RayToal third party class, or for example Array class (as I mentioned before someone already wrote the right answer, and hopefully s/he will post it again soon)

Comment: Sorry, that was me. I answered it right away but then I deleted it when I saw the words "external class" and wanted to ask you for clarification. I have undeleted it, hope it helps.

Comment: @RayToal it did, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SayHello2` should be a non-arrow function to access the properties you are looking for:

```
PersonClass.prototype.SayHello2 = function () {
  console.log(this.name, this.type);
};
```

which produces:

```
"Ned Stark",  "human"
```

Don't forget you also have access to the `constructor` property of an instance as well, allowing you to access everything associate with your classes.

Answer (score 1):

This should works:

```js
    PersonClass.prototype.SayHello2 = function() {
      console.log(this.name);
    };

    aria.SayHello2(); // "Ned Stark"
```