# Prototypes On Objects That Don't Return Themselves

Tags: javascript, prototype

I've been refactoring my code for better performance. This is a simple version of the problem code:

```
function Thing(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
function Square(x,  y, size) {
    var self = new Thing(x, y);
    self.size = size;
    return self;
}
```

And at the time of creating this it worked perfectly fine. The problem now, though, is that I cannot find any simple ways of creating a prototype for **square**.

Is there anything I'm missing? If not, are there any ways of implementing this kind of "extends" concept *and* integrating prototypes without rewriting everything?

Comment: Don't know why you're writing it that way, but you can invoke the `Thing` function on the `Square` instance. `Thing.call(this, x, y); this.size = size;`

Comment: @doodlemeister It's what happens when you follow old javascript tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has the exact answer you want: [Another Stack overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163341/multiple-inheritance-prototypes-in-javascript)

Use Mixins, not as simple as Java or whatever else you may be used to but still possible to do what it is that you want. You will need to write code that is slightly different is all.

Comment: If you find a question that has already been answered, please comment or flag it as a duplicate

Comment: Thanks, should've known it was already asked at some point.. just took some different keywords I suppose