# It is possible to inherit from multiple prototypes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a prototype that inherits from two different prototypes. I know I can achieve this easily with object concatenation or create methods in the constructor function, but I want to have functions that would be saved in the prototype chain instead.

Let say I have `Human` and `Robot`, and I want to create a new type `RobotMan`:

```js
function Human(name, hp){
  this.hp = hp || 100
  this.name = name
}

Human.prototype.eat = function (){
  this.hp += 50
  console.log(`current hp: ${this.hp}`)
}
```

```js
function Robot(name, fuel){
  this.fuel = fuel || 100
  this.name = name
}

Robot.prototype.refuel = function (){
  this.fuel += 25
  console.log(`current fuel: ${this.fuel}`)
}
```

How can I combine to prototype into one and make `RobotMan` inherit from both `Human` and `Robot`?

```js
function RobotMan(name, hp, fuel){
  Human.call(this, name, hp)
  Robot.call(this, name, fuel)
}

RobotMan.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype) //? How should I write this line correctly?
RobotMan.prototype.constructor = RobotMan
```

Comment: "*I know I can achieve this easily with object concatenation*" Is there something that's missing in the question because `RobotMan.prototype = Object.assign({}, Human.prototype, Robot.prototype)` seems correct for your use case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple inheritance/prototypes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163341/multiple-inheritance-prototypes-in-javascript)

Comment: @VLAZ I tried that put somehow it didn't work previously, but it worked now. I think I have  made and mistake somewhere in my code. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method. This method is used to copy own enumerable property from one or more sources to an object.

The `assign` method returns the new object and I've assigned that object as `RobotMan` prototype.

```js
function Human(name, hp) {
  this.hp = hp || 100;
  this.name = name;
}

Human.prototype.eat = function () {
  this.hp += 50;
  console.log(`current hp: ${this.hp}`);
};

function Robot(name, fuel) {
  this.fuel = fuel || 100;
  this.name = name;
}

Robot.prototype.refuel = function () {
  this.fuel += 25;
  console.log(`current fuel: ${this.fuel}`);
};

function RobotMan(name, hp, fuel) {
  Human.call(this, name, hp);
  Robot.call(this, name, fuel);
}

RobotMan.prototype = Object.assign({}, Human.prototype, Robot.prototype);
const robotMan = new RobotMan("robotman", 50, 40);
robotMan.eat();
robotMan.refuel();
```

Comment: I just realize that this is not the correct answer. Doing so will only copy and take a snapshot of the `Human.prototype` and `Robot.prototype` when `Object.assign` is called. If I mutate `Robot.prototype` after `Object.assign()`, `RobotMan.prototype` will not be changed.