# Is there any way to extends another class instead of Component class in react-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, class, oop

I am developing a website using react-js. i am implementing middlware functions by extending to another class.

i have multiple Components like

```
export default class Login extends React.Component{} // for public group
export default class Register extends React.Component{} // for public group

export default class Profile extends React.Component{} // for Private group
export default class Settings extends React.Component{} // for Private group
export default class EditProfile extends React.Component{} // for Private group
```

How wonder if i create two class one `class Private` and another will be `class public` that extends to the my private and public group components that call one function for checking that there Auth token is still valid or not by this i do not have to call same function again and again in every component i tried this but my IDE says

```
Parsing error: Classes can only extend a single class.eslint
```

If this is a dumb idea please comment me how you do it without `Redux`.

the final code will be like

```
export default class Login extends Public, React.Component{} // for public group
export default class Register extends Public, React.Component{} // for public group

export default class Profile extends Private, React.Component{} // for Private group
export default class Settings extends private, React.Component{} // for Private group
export default class EditProfile extends Private, React.Component{} // for Private group
```

Sorry for poor english.

Comment: Make sure Public and Private classes extend React.Component. Then extend your classes with Public or Private only, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no multiple inheritance in JavaScript.**

But you can do some workarounds. Ex [Multiple inheritance/prototypes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163341/multiple-inheritance-prototypes-in-javascript)

But in React you should extend just from one Class. So, you should encapsulate all needed functionality in the Private and Public classes which should be extended from React.Component.

```js
class Public extends React.Component {}
class Private extends React.Component {}

export default class Login extends Public {}
export default class Register extends Public {}

export default class Profile extends Private {}
export default class Settings extends Private {}
export default class EditProfile extends Private {}
```

**If you want to get functionality to just check if a user is authorized without `Redux`.**

You can create a HOC. You can read more here https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#use-hocs-for-cross-cutting-concerns

```js
function private(Component) {
  const isTokenValid = ... // here your stuff

  if (isTokenValid) return Component;
  else ... // do your needed stuff. For example, redirect to the Login page.
}

// I'm not sure if this HOC(High Order Component) is needed, but anyway
function public(Component) {
  const isTokenValid = ... // here your stuff

  if (isTokenValid) // do your needed stuff. For example, redirect to the Main page.
  else return Component; 
}

export class Login extends React.Component {}
export class Register extends React.Component {}

export class Profile extends React.Component {}
export class Settings extends React.Component {}
export class EditProfile extends React.Component {}

export const ProtectedLogin = public(Login);
export const ProtectedRegister =  public(Register);

export const ProtectedProfile = private(Profile);
export const ProtectedSettings = private(Settings);
export const ProtectedEditProfile = private(EditProfile);
```