# Is multiple inheritance possible in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a situation here. I have two modules(nothing but javascript function) defined like this:

**Module1:**

```
define(function(){
    function A() {
        var that = this;
        that.data = 1
        // ..
    }
    return A; 
});
```

**Module2:**

```
define(function(){   
    function B() {
        var that = this;
        that.data = 1;
        // ...
    }
    return B; 
});
```

How to inhert both modules inside other module?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have inheritance, it uses prototypes.

Comment: Questions about multiple inheritance in JavaScript [have been asked on Stack Overflow many times before](https://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:stackoverflow.com+multiple+inheritance+javascript&oq=site:stackoverflow.com+multiple+inheritance+javascript&gs_l=hp.3...926.20236.1.20465.80.74.3.3.3.0.169.4177.71j3.74.0...0.0...1c.1.14.hp.VBc-U-g0D_M&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.dmg&fp=e16b3377a0a5d434&biw=1366&bih=639). You might be able to find a solution from one of these duplicate questions.

Comment: @Anderson Care to link to a duplicate?

Comment: @deceze This looks like a very close match: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887828/does-javascript-support-multiple-inheritance-like-c

Comment: those links are good too :)

Comment: @Antimony - it has prototype-based inheritance rather than class-based inheritance.  It's still inheritance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) In js everything is just an object.

2) Javascript inheritance uses prototype inheritance and not classic inheritance.

JavaScript doesn't support multiple inheritance.
To have both of them inside the same class try to use mixins that are better anyhow:

```
function extend(destination, source) {
  for (var k in source) {
    if (source.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      destination[k] = source[k];
    }
 }
 return destination; 
 }

 var C = Object.create(null);
 extend(C.prototype,A);
 extend(C.prototype,B);
```

mixins:

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/

inheritance in js:

http://howtonode.org/prototypical-inheritance

http://killdream.github.io/blog/2011/10/understanding-javascript-oop/index.html

Comment: So... is multiple *prototypical* inheritance possible...?

Comment: use mixins, it's the closest there is. Js doesn't enforce structure or base class methods or properties..in js everything is just an object..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go a little demonstration of the functionality you want to achieve:

```
var obj1 = function() {
  var privateMember = "anything";
  this.item1 = 1;
}

var obj2 = function() {
  this.item2 = 2;
}

var objInheritsBoth = function() {
  obj1.call(this); // call obj1 in this context
  obj2.call(this);
  this.item3 = 3;
}

var x = new objInheritsBoth();

console.log(x.item1, x.item2, x.item3); // 1 2 3
```